# url rewrite apache for wildcard domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite rule for wildcard domains all requests are send to index.php on main domain. This is content for my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.us$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/domain\.us\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

And it works like it's supposed to work...perfect!
But recently I had to change the url structure of the whole website, that is fine old urls will simple show 404 though few old urls are important to me and I want to redirect them 301 to new url. For example:

> somesubdomain.maindomain.com/oldcontent/

I want to reditect

> somesubdomain.maindomain.com/importantdir/oldcontent/

Whatever I tried I ended up with a redirection loop (to many redirects at once).
I have like thousands of urls but only want to 301 redirect few of them.

Comment: do you want to make this redirection on main domain?

Comment: @Max P No. As explained above: from one subdomain url to another subdomain url.